# How to change font style for specific text instead of whole text in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make something like an online txt editor. The problem is that when I try to apply `document.getElementById("textArea").style.fontWeight="bold";`, the whole textarea changes to bold.I just want the text while bold is toggled to change to bold, something like microsoft word I guess. Question: how to change font style for specific text in textarea. I am a beginner so I only know how to use javascript and jquery.
**HTML**

```
<button onclick="Bold()"><h3>Bold</h3></button>
<textarea id="textArea" class="Textarea" placeholder="Click to Type" cols="50"></textarea>
```

**Javascript**

```
function Bold(){
  if (document.getElementById("textArea").style.fontWeight=="bold"){
    document.getElementById("textArea").style.fontWeight=null;
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("textArea").style.fontWeight="bold";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `textarea` field because you only can set styles in HTML elements. You must use a element with `contenteditable` attribute and set the style in the HTML format to customize your input style the way you want.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
<div id="textarea" contenteditable="true">
    <b style="color: red">My bold text in red.</b> =)
</div>
```

You can get the value from the `contenteditable` field with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"); // contenteditable element
    var textarea_value = textarea.innerHTML; // contenteditable element value

   // getting specific text, here we are getting the bold text
   var bold_element = textarea.querySelectorAll('b')[0].innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: But how to access specific text in the div with javascript?

Comment: Read my answer again. I explained how you can do this.

Comment: But how to bold text that is typed after bold is toggled.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean changing the bold text in the editablecontent area? You just need to press `CTRL` + `B`. But making the texts bold isn't your first question, I am now getting confused about what you want us to help you with.

Comment: I have a "bold" button. After this button is pressed, the words that are typed after it is pressed will become bold. My problem is that I don't know how to do this. All I know is how to make text bold.

Comment: The simpliest way to do that is with DOM `execCommand()` function. You only have to create a function to do that, like `function toogleTextBold() { document.execCommand('bold'); }`. This will toggle the bold text in the contenteditable area on and off.

Comment: I'm keeping answering your new questions but, as I said, this is not your main question, your main question has already been answered, so if I helped you, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. Good Morning!

Comment: You helped a lot. Thanks. I have marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

A little late for answer, but still can be useful for people. "textarea" is difficult is difficult to style, so you can go for "div" with "contenteditable" property. First HTML:

```
<div id="textAreaContainer">
  <div id='myTextArea' contenteditable autofocus></div>
  <button type="button" id="myButton">Click Me for Style</button>
</div>
```

Then, 1) grab the content of the div, 2)Split it according to your need, 3) Style the part you want and export it back to the div area. Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction(){
  const insertedText = document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerHTML;
  const insertedTextCount = insertedText.length;
  const partText1 = insertedText.substring(0, 100);
  const partText2 = insertedText.substring(100, insertedTextCount);
  document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerHTML = partText1+'<span style="font-weight: bold;">'+partText2+"</span>";
  return;
};
```

So, first click will work as planned but any following click without refreshing the page will complicate the textarea content. If you want following clicks to update nicely the styled parts of the textarea, then you will need one more line of code. It will clear the unvisible span tags inside the textarea before styling it. Add the line of code as shown below, and make a small change in the name of first variable:

```
const insertedText0 = document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerHTML;
const insertedText = insertedText0.replace(/<span.*>/gi, "\n");
const insertedTextCount = insertedText.length;
```